# AJAX (JSON) problems with NGRepeat

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

I've got problem with outputting my JSON from server (Node.js) to NGrepeat.

I have tried a lot and debugged with both Firebug and Firefox Web Inspector.

For some reason it will not show the data from the JSON, even then the JSON looks correct when I output it in the Firebug console (using Firefox 39.0).

[image: screenshot]

JSON:

```
[{ nr:"1", svenska:"test2", spanska:"testo2"},{ nr:"2", svenska:"test3", spanska:"testo3"},{ nr:"3", svenska:"test4", spanska:"testo4"},{ nr:"4", svenska:"test5", spanska:"testo5"},{ nr:"5", svenska:"test6", spanska:"testo6"}]
```

Angular.js

```
    /**
     *
     * The client Angular.JS main file for the project
     */


    var glosorApp = angular.module('glosorApp',['directives']);   /* */


    angular.module('directives', [])
    .directive('toggleClass', function () {
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div ng-click="localFunction()" ng-class="selected"    ng-transclude></div>',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.localFunction = function () {
                scope.model.value = scope.$id;
            };
            scope.$watch('model.value', function () {
                if (scope.model.value === scope.$id) {
                    scope.selected = "active";
                } else {
                    scope.selected = '';
                }
            });
        }
    };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
    });




    glosorApp.controller('listController', function ($scope, $http) {

       $http.post(PROJEKT_SOKVAG+'/_myroute', 
                    {type:AJAX.LISTA_GLOSOR_CLI_R}).success( function(data) {

                                console.log("Kommer hit lookdeep: "+lookdeep(data.data));   


                                $scope.glosor = data.data;
                        //      $scope.$apply();                                                    

                                console.log("Kommer hit lookdeep: $scope.glosor "+lookdeep($scope.glosor)); 

                        });       

    });





function ajaxanrop(callback, data_) {
     $.ajax({
            url: PROJEKT_SOKVAG+'_myroute',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data_ ,      // the data that should be sent to server
            success: function(data) { if ( callback ) callback(data); },
            error: function() { if ( callback ) callback(null); },
            complete: function() { /* console.log("Klart"); */ } 
      });   

    }
```

HTML (EJS template)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="glosorApp" ng-init="model = { value: 'dsf'}">
<head>
<title>Glosor</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var PROJEKT_SOKVAG="<%=project_path %>", LoginUser="<%= user.username %>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w42.se/webbroot/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://w42.se/<%=project_path %>/jquery-ui-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w42.se<%=project_path %>/lookdeep.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w42.se<%=project_path %>/constants.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w42.se<%=project_path %>/clientAngular.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="vald_sida" style="display:none;" class="mentorer"></div>
<p>Anv&auml;ndarnamn: <%= user.username %></p>
<p>Email: <%= user.email %></p>

<p><a href="<%=project_path %>/_logout">Log out</a></p>

    <div id="wrapper"  ng-controller="listController" >

    <p><a href="<%=project_path %>/_laggtillglosor">L&auml;gg till Glosor</a></p>
    <p><a href="<%=project_path %>/_account">Testa Glosor</a></p>       

    <div class="clear"></div>


    <div class="list">

        <div class="filterarea">
        <h4>S&ouml;kning</h4>
            <div>       
                    <span>Nr: <input ng-model="search.nr" ng-model-options="{debounce: 20000}"></span>
                    <span>Svenska: <input ng-model="search.svenska" ng-model-options="{debounce: 20000}"></span>
                    <span>Spanske: <input ng-model="search.spanska" ng-model-options="{debounce: 20000}"></span>
                    <span>Po&auml;ng: <input ng-model="search.poang" ng-model-options="{debounce: 20000}"></span>

            </div>

        </div>
            <div class="pad clearfix">          
                <h4>Resultat</h4>       

                V&auml;lj: alla <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master"><br/> 
                  <div ng-form="">
                <div class="list">
                        <div class="thead">
                            <div>
                                <span class="sortable"><a href="" 
                                ng-click="predicate = 'nr'; reverse=!reverse">#</a></span>  
                                <span class="sortable td"><a href="" 
                                ng-click="predicate = 'svenska'; reverse=!reverse">Svenska</a></span>
                                <span class="sortable td"><a href="" 
                                ng-click="predicate = 'spanska'; reverse=!reverse">Spanska</a></span>
                                <span class="sortable td"><a href="" 
                                ng-click="predicate = 'poang'; reverse=!reverse">Po&auml;ng</a></span>                                              
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tbody">             
                            <div ng-repeat="glosa in filter_glosor = (glosor | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:search)">                      
                                    <div class="tr" toggle-class="" model="model">                  
                                    <span class="td">{{glosor.nr}}</span>  
                                    <span class="td">{{glosor.svenska}}</span>
                                    <span class="td">{{glosor.spanska}}</span>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the `ng-repeat` issue, it looks like you're using a filter incorrectly. Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="glosa in glosor | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:search">
```

**NB** If you're trying to GET data, you should use `$http.get` instead of the `$http.post(PROJEKT_SOKVAG+'/_myroute',` you have.

It will save confusion down the road when maintaining the app.

Comment: Huh? Why does it matter if the data comes from a GET or a POST response?

Comment: For starters, because it's the correct HTTP verb to use when getting data.

Comment: That entirely depends on the context. For example, if the request modifies data, you should be using a POST.

Comment: True. But the context here (as best I can tell with variable names in a language I don't know) is just requesting data.

Comment: Aside from that, how would it fix the problem at hand? OP says the received data is OK. So changing it to a GET wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: You are correct. I should have just made that a comment. I have edited the answer to point out the possible issue with the filter.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the filter didn't solve the problem.

 I changed to  <div ng-repeat="glosa in glosor"> and it still doesn't show the data that is stored in the array glosor.   

 The strange thing is that, when I put for example {{glosor[1].svenska}} in the HTML, it shows the data that is stored in that object correctly. The data in  $scope.glosor looks fine in general when I output it to the console, as well. 

But, NGRepeat creates empty span-tags, when I look at the HTML in the Firefox Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the error that I made, and it was a ridiculously simple error. Quite embarrasing actually... ;-)

I put glosor.svenska instead of glosa.svenska in the repeated block (inside the NGRepeat).

That's the bad thing with having the array name and the element name too similar, you might mix them up.

This means that I put the array instead of the repeated single array element inside the repeated block.